# Exception while deserializing with @JsonRootName

Tags: java, json-deserialization, jackson2

Desirialization does not work when there are multiple nodes available at same level as value provided in the JsonRootName

Note: 
Wrapper is configured with following:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

@JsonRootName(value = "response")
public class UserProfile {
  String name;
  String link;
}
```

Input JSON (which works):

```
{
  "response": {
    "name": "User one:",
    "link": "Some Link"
  }
}
```

Input JSON (which does not work)

```
{
  "response": {
    "name": "User one:",
    "link": "Some Link"
  }, 
  "apiVersion" : 1.0
}
```

Adding a wrapper for with fields `response` and `apiVersion` wouls solve this problem which would defeat the purpose of using tag `JsonRootName`

How to deserialize when there is more than one field at root level (without using another wrapper class) ?

Comment: So, your question is: what is the purpose of `@JsonRootName`??

Comment: How to deserialize this type of structure without using another wrapper?

Comment: Well, I don't know if your can do that ... what you're expecting about `@JsonRootName` using the second type of input (the one that does not work): deserializes the response object and skip the `apiVersion` attribute?